# Is this matrix in row echelon form?

Tags: matrices

Is this matrix in row echelon form?
3x3 matrix is:
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
    1 & 3 & 4 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
Last element of `2nd row` is `1`, in a cell above it is a `4`. I think Row echelon form allows `4` and `1` in this form. But is that `0` in `2nd row`(which has `3` above it) is allowed in `row echelon form`? So the question is,'Is `3` allowed above `0` in row echelon form?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be in Row Echelon Form requires two things of a matrix:

- All non-zero rows are above any all-zero row.
- The leftmost non-zero element (the pivot) in any row is to occur strictly to the right of any pivot in the rows above it.

So the given matrix checks out okay.   It is Row Echelon.

You *can*, however, *reduce* it further by a row operation as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix as given **is** indeed in row echelon form, but not reduced row echelon form.  For the latter, replace the $4$ by a $0$.